# Configuring ObjecMapper null serialization after first serialization does not have effect

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, jackson2

Stumbled on this behavior when making some experiments with `ObjectMapper`. See Junit5 test cases below and what those print for me in comments.

```
class TestIt {

    private ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    private TestClass testClass = new TestClass();

    @Getter @Setter
    public class TestClass {
        private final String value = LocalDate.now().toString();
        private String valueLeftNull;
    }
    
    @Test
    void defaultMapping() throws JsonProcessingException {
        System.out.println(om.writeValueAsString(testClass));
        // {"value":"2020-11-02","valueLeftNull":null}
    }

    @Test
    void nonNull() throws JsonProcessingException {
        om.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
        System.out.println(om.writeValueAsString(testClass));
        // {"value":"2020-11-02"}
    }

    @Test
    void both() throws JsonProcessingException {
        System.out.println(om.writeValueAsString(testClass));
        om.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
        System.out.println(om.writeValueAsString(testClass));
        System.out.println(om.writeValueAsString(new TestClass()));
        // {"value":"2020-11-02","valueLeftNull":null}
        // {"value":"2020-11-02","valueLeftNull":null}
        // {"value":"2020-11-02","valueLeftNull":null}

    }

}
```

The last one `both()` is what I am wondering. Is it normal functionality that `ObjectMapper` ignores the inclusion instruction after the first serialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `Jackson` creates [BeanSerializer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/BeanSerializer.html) instance for each `POJO` class. It is created on demand when is needed and **cached**. So it's configuration depends from current state of `ObjectMapper` and if you change `ObjectMapper` you need to clear cache:

```
((DefaultSerializerProvider) om.getSerializerProvider()).flushCachedSerializers();
```

to force `ObjectMapper` to create new instance of `BeanSerializer`.

Take a look at documentation for [BeanSerializerFactory](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/BeanSerializerFactory.html):

> ...
> Finally, since all caching is handled by the serializer provider
> (not factory) and there is no configurability, this factory is
> stateless. This means that a global singleton instance can be used.

and [cachedSerializersCount](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/DefaultSerializerProvider.html#cachedSerializersCount--) method:

> Method that can be used to determine how many serializers this
> provider is caching currently (if it does caching: default
> implementation does) Exact count depends on what kind of serializers
> get cached; default implementation caches all serializers, including
> ones that are eagerly constructed (for optimal access speed)

Probably the best solution would be to create two instances of `ObjectMapper`:

```
class TestIt {

    private JsonMapper nonNullMapper = JsonMapper.builder()
                .serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
                .build();
    private JsonMapper defaultMapper = JsonMapper.builder().build();
    private TestClass testClass = new TestClass();

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class TestClass {
        private final String value = LocalDate.now().toString();
        private String valueLeftNull;
    }

    void defaultMapping() throws JsonProcessingException {
        System.out.println(defaultMapper.writeValueAsString(testClass));
    }

    void nonNull() throws JsonProcessingException {
        System.out.println(nonNullMapper.writeValueAsString(testClass));
    }

    void both() throws JsonProcessingException {
        System.out.println(defaultMapper.writeValueAsString(testClass));
        System.out.println(nonNullMapper.writeValueAsString(testClass));
        System.out.println(nonNullMapper.writeValueAsString(new TestClass()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice work. This is not any real problem but something that just made me thinking why. `flushCachedSerializers()` worked. It is a bit confusing that it is allowed to call but it does nothing for classes already serialized once. Maybe it could make this flush upon setting inclusion or throw an exception. And maybe there is a good reason why it is not doing so.

Comment: @pirho, since `Jackson` introduced `JsonMapper` and builder pattern it is probably the best way to create new `ObjectMapper`. In case you need different configuration you need to create new instance. Easy and this way we avoid situations like this.