# Unexpected serialization behavior with configured Jackson ObjectMapper

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I am using Jackson 2.10.5 to serialize the same `java.util.Date` object three times.

1. The first time, with a basic Jackson `ObjectMapper`.  I see the timestamp.
2. Then I configure the same `ObjectMapper`, and rewrite.  I get the same result.
3. Then I construct a new `ObjectMapper`, configure it the same way.  I get a different result, the class name and the timestamp in a JSON list.

The configuration is intended to tell the `ObjectMapper` to include the class name of  every object *except `java.util.Date`* as a JSON property.

So I have two questions.  The first is why is the date object serialized differently in the third case?  Any advice on using the `PolymorphicTypeMapper` differently would be appreciated.

The second is why the first and second are the same (is it because the Object mapper has a cache (ouch!)?).

[EDIT: I should have mentioned that the use case for this is as a JSON provider for Jersey.  I have a way of generating and configuring an `ObjectMapper` at launch time, but the (in)ability to configure per-write is just for the test code above.]

```
private PolymorphicTypeValidator getPTV() {
    return BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator.builder()
            .denyForExactBaseType(Date.class)
            .build();
}


@Test
public void serializationTest() {
    try {
        Date now = new Date();

        // Create an object mapper and serialize the date
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        String serialized1 = om.writeValueAsString(now); // result: 1605744866827

        om.activateDefaultTypingAsProperty(getPTV(), ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.EVERYTHING, "@class");
        String serialized2 = om.writeValueAsString(now); // result: 1605744866827

        ObjectMapper om2 = new ObjectMapper();
        om2.activateDefaultTypingAsProperty(getPTV(), ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.EVERYTHING, "@class");
        String serialized3 = om2.writeValueAsString(now); // result: ["java.util.Date",1605744866827]

        Logger.getLogger(SerializationTest.class).info(serialized1);
        Logger.getLogger(SerializationTest.class).info(serialized2);
        Logger.getLogger(SerializationTest.class).info(serialized3);

        Assert.assertEquals("Unexpected change in serialization 1-2", serialized1, serialized2);
        Assert.assertEquals("Unexpected change in serialization 1-3", serialized1, serialized3);

    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
INFO  2020-11-18 16:14:27,065 [main] <> test.SerializationTest : 1605744866827
INFO  2020-11-18 16:14:27,066 [main] <> test.SerializationTest : 1605744866827
INFO  2020-11-18 16:14:27,066 [main] <> test.SerializationTest : ["java.util.Date",1605744866827]

org.junit.ComparisonFailure: Unexpected change in serialization 1-3 
Expected :1605744866827
Actual   :["java.util.Date",1605744866827]
```

Comment: `ObjectMapper` instance once configured and used should not be reconfigured. `ObjectMapper` uses internal cache for serializer and deserializer instances. It is much better to create `N` different instances of  `ObjectMapper` with different configuration than reconfiguring the same instance `N` times. Problems like this could appear. Take a look at similar question: [Configuring ObjecMapper null serialization after first serialization does not have effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64642641/configuring-objecmapper-null-serialization-after-first-serialization-does-not-ha)

Comment: @Michał Ziober Thanks.  This is exactly what Andreas said yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Read the **documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html), which says *(**bold** highlights by me)*:

> Mapper instances are fully thread-safe provided that **ALL configuration** of the instance **occurs before ANY read or write calls**. If configuration of a mapper is **modified after first usage, changes may or may not take effect**, and configuration calls themselves **may fail**. If you need to use different configuration, you have two main possibilities:
>
> - Construct and use `ObjectReader` for reading, `ObjectWriter` for writing. Both types are fully immutable and you can freely create new instances with different configuration using either factory methods of `ObjectMapper`, or readers/writers themselves. Construction of new `ObjectReader`s and `ObjectWriter`s is a very light-weight operation so it is usually appropriate to create these on per-call basis, as needed, for configuring things like optional indentation of JSON.
> - If the specific kind of configurability is not available via `ObjectReader` and `ObjectWriter`, you may need to use **multiple `ObjectMapper`** instead (for example: you can not change mix-in annotations on-the-fly; or, set of custom (de)serializers). To help with this usage, you may want to use method `copy()` which creates a clone of the mapper with specific configuration, and allows configuration of the copied instance before it gets used. Note that `copy()` operation is as expensive as constructing a new `ObjectMapper` instance: if possible, you should still pool and reuse mappers if you intend to use them for multiple operations.

Comment: Thanks so much.  That is indeed clear.  This question only arose as a consequence of the other more important question though.  Do you have any thoughts on that?  Thanks.

Comment: @dbp I just answered that: 1) *"why is the date object serialized differently in the third case?"* Because `activateDefaultTypingAsProperty(...)` **took effect** on `om2`. --- 2) *"why the first and second are the same"* Because `activateDefaultTypingAsProperty(...)` **did not take effect** on `om`.

Comment: It is true that ```om2``` is configured with default typing.  However the ```PolymorphicTypeValidator``` explicitly excludes ```java.util.Date``` from having its type included.  The question is why does ```om2``` produce a different result from ```om```?

Comment: @dbp Then you should create a new question and specifically ask that, because that is certainly not how I read the question. Besides, you're only supposed to ask one question per question.

Comment: I appreciate your thoughts.